# Symbol O_DIRECT could not be resolved

Tags: c

Can you please tell me what is wrong with the following code ?
For some reason the compiler refuses to recognize the O_DIRECT flag.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int fd;
   fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact command that you use to compile the file, and the full output.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and strangely enough, the code compiles and runs but I get the following warning from the compiler: Symbol O_DIRECT could not be resolved

Comment: @Robert777 Don't worry about that, then. It's just the indexing parser. You can resolve it by dumping the predefined macros from the compiler and feeding them into the indexing configuration control panel. Also double check that it has the right header search paths. Or just ignore/disable those warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. It's just the indexing parser which decides the text editor syntax highlighting and (ideally) links identifiers to definitions.

You can resolve the problem by dumping the predefined macros from the compiler and feeding them into the indexing configuration control panel. Also double check that it has the right header search paths.

Or just ignore/disable those warnings.